# What makes SOCKS proxy a layer 5 proxy and HTTP proxy a layer 7 proxy, instead of layer 3?

Tags: http, proxy, socks

I'm confused because it seems like they both operate at layer 3, since they route traffic from the client through a proxy server.

I did several searches on Google about it and all it says is that they work at levels 5 and 7, but it doesn't say why they are classified this way.

Answer (score 1):

> it seems like they both operate at layer 3

Where did you get that idea from? Do you know what the [OSI Model](https://www.imperva.com/learn/application-security/osi-model/) is, and what its levels are?

IP routing operates at level 3 (the "Network Layer"). TCP/UDP operates at layer 4 (the "Transport Layer").  But since both SOCKS and HTTP run on top of TCP/UDP, they can't operate at level 4 or lower, so they have to operate on layer 5 or higher.

SOCKS operates at layer 5 (the "Session Layer"), because there is no level 6 (the "Presentation Layer") data for it to manage (charsets, encryption, compression, etc).  It is just facilitating connections between parties, it doesn't care what they exchange with each other.  So, SOCKS doesn't need to operate above level 5.

HTTP, on the other hand, is a protocol between software applications. It  deals with level 6 data and higher application data, so it operates at level 7 (the "Application Layer").  And thus, HTTP proxies also operate at level 7, since they are specialized implementations of HTTP.